# React select multi value with radius does not center items

Tags: css, reactjs, react-select, border-radius

When adding a radius to multi select values in React using react-select, the text and remove button do not remain centered within the bubble at certain scales. Zooming in and out of a browser can produce the results,

Aligned text and button

[image]

Above the text and remove button are aligned.

Misaligned text and button at different scale

[image]

In this scale you can see 'Ocean' has fallen below the remove button.

How can I ensure these are aligned, and centered vertically within the radius of the bubble?

```
import React from "react";
import { ColourOption, colourOptions } from "./docs/data";
import Select, { StylesConfig } from "react-select";

const colourStyles: StylesConfig<ColourOption, true> = {
  control: (styles) => ({
    ...styles,
    fontSize: 17,
  }),
  multiValue: (styles, { data }) => {
    return {
      ...styles,
      borderRadius: 27,
      border: "1px black !important",
    };
  },
};

export default () => (
  <Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={false}
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[0], colourOptions[1]]}
    isMulti
    options={colourOptions}
    styles={colourStyles}
  />
);
```

I have tried adding `div: {'display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center'}` within the multiValue styles.

Comment: Since this is at its heart a CSS question and not a React question, you likely get more responses if you create a StackSnippet [mcve] with the rendered HTML and CSS instead of the React code.